# QLocalSocket doesn't send anything

Tags: c++, qt, ipc, qlocalsocket

well, i'm still trying to get a IPC running through a QLocalSocket. 
Obviously my socket connects, the connection gets accepted, but when i try to send something

```
void ServiceConnector::send_MessageToServer(QString message) {

    if(!connected){
        m_socket->connectToServer(m_serverName);
        m_socket->waitForConnected();

    }

    char str[] = {"hallo welt\0"};
    int c = m_socket->write(str,strlen(str));
    qDebug() << "written: " << c;
}
```

i get no response...the server's socket does just nothing.

server's read implementation:

```
void ClientHandler::socket_new_connection() {

    logToFile("incoming connection");

    clientConnection = m_server->nextPendingConnection();

    socket_StateChanged(clientConnection->state());

    auto conn = connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(socket_disconnected()));
    conn = connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketState)),this,SLOT(socket_StateChanged(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketState)));
    conn = connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(socket_readReady()));

    clientConnection->waitForReadyRead();
    socket_readReady();
}
void ClientHandler::socket_readReady(){
    logToFile("socket is ready to be read");

    logToFile((clientConnection->isOpen())? "open: true":"open: false");
    logToFile((clientConnection->isReadable())? "readable: true":"readable: false");

    QDataStream in(clientConnection);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    if (clientConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16)) {
        return;
    }

    QString message;
    in >> message;

    logToFile("Message recieved" + message);

    send(message);
    emit messageReceived(message);
}
```

outputs:

client:

```
[Debug]: ConnectingState 
[Debug]: ConnectedState 
[Debug]: socket_connected 
[Debug]: written:  10
```

server:

```
[Debug]: incoming connection
[Debug]: socket is ready to be read
[Debug]: open: true
[Debug]: readable: true
```

the socket's readReady() signal is never emitted, so i decided to use

```
clientConnection->waitForReadyRead();
socket_readReady();
```

...but obviously that doesn't work either. `waitForReadyRead` is fired immediately after the `write` function of the client, which i think means that it is now ready to read...

[edit] the `auto conn = connection(...)` was for debugging, to check if they connect properly....they do

Comment: `if (clientConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16)) {` this check looks fishy.  Try removing it, and see what happens.

Comment: this just checks if at least one byte is readable. i removed it for debugging, but that doesn't change anything; there is still nothing to read

Comment: It seems the client is getting a connect signal and then immediately sending data to the server. Whenever I write client-server code, I always have the client connect, then on a connection, the server sends an 'ok' data packet. When the client receives 'ok', it then proceeds to make requests to the server. I wonder if your client sending data first is causing it to be missed by the server's readyRead().

Comment: well, that's not the problem, the problem is that the socket won't write. if i give out the buytesToWrite(), it's the same amount of bytes like it was written by the write() function. but if i do waitForBytesWritten(), it just hangs there until the timeout occurs. also flush won't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

Note: you should really check the return value of waitForConnected(). There's no point in proceeding further if the client doesn't manage to connect to the server.

But I think your actual issue is that you're writing a simple 8-bit string like "hallo welt\0" but you're reading with QDataStream which expects a binary format (for QString, that means unicode, and length first), this doesn't match.